# Postback and scroll position

Tags: asp.net, scroll, postback

I am developing a website with ASP. net. When I postback from any component, first load the page and THEN sets the position of the scroll. The question is: How to set the scroll BEFORE the page loads?

Greetings!

Comment: What do you mean? Page *had* to load first before client-side functions like scroll could work.

Comment: Yes, but it gives me the page and THEN sets the scroll. Visually is wrong.
Sorry, it's hard to explain

Comment: Could you please post the code you use to maintain scroll on postback?

Comment: I use MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback = "true" in each of the content pages.

Comment: Do you want to return to arbitrary scrolling position, or is it always the same, e.g. some textbox on a form?

Comment: is an arbitrary position. The html code is:

http://pastebin.com/kegf8GUr

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to put the controls in an **< asp:UpdatePanel >** and do an async post back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this. Something like:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(#id).scrollTop(100);
});
```